# Python: Web Scraping one of two same classes

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Main_Page'
r = requests.get(url)

Soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")
List = Soup.find("div",class_="enws-mainpage-widget-content", id="enws-mainpage-newtexts-content").find_all('a')
ebooks=[]
i=0
for ebook in List:
    x=ebook.get('title')
    for ch in x:
        if(ch==":"):
            x=""
    if x!="":
        ebooks.append(x)
        i=i+1
        

inputnumber=0
while inputnumber<len(ebooks):
    print(inputnumber+1, " - ", ebooks[inputnumber])
    inputnumber=inputnumber+1
input=int(input("Please select a book: "))
selectedbook = Soup.find("a", title=ebooks[input-1])
print(selectedbook['title'])
url1 = "https://en.wikisource.org/"+selectedbook['href']
r1 = requests.get(url1)
Soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.text, "html5lib")
List1 = Soup1.find("div", class_="prp-pages-output").find_all('p')
words=str(List1)
ebook1= open('ebook1.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
ebook1.write(words)
ebook1.close()
```

From this website: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/May_(M%C3%A1cha)   I want to get the text of the story but as result I get this in the created file:

```
[<p><span style="font-size:249%;"><b>May</b></span>
</p>, <p><span style="font-size: 144%;">A ROMANTIC POEM</span><br/>
<span style="font-size: 92%;"><i>by</i></span><br/>
<span style="font-size: 120%;"><span class="plainlinks"><a href="/wiki/Author:Karel_Hynek_M%C3%A1cha" title="Author:Karel Hynek Mácha">KAREL HYNEK MACHA</a></span></span>
</p>, <p><span style="font-size: 83%;"><i>Translated from the Czech by</i></span><br/>
<span style="font-size: 120%;"><span class="plainlinks"><a href="/wiki/Author:Roderick_Aldrich_Ginsburg" title="Author:Roderick Aldrich Ginsburg">RODERICK A. GINSBURG</a></span></span></p>]
```

It seems there are two div with the same classes but I want to get the second. Code takes the first one. Whwat should I do?

Comment: I think if you replace `Soup1.find("div", class_="prp-pages-output")` with `Soup1.find_all(class_='prp-pages-output')[1]` you will get the second `div`.

Comment: File "homework.py", line 32, in <module> List1 = Soup1.find_all("div", class_="prp-pages-output").find_all('p') File "C:\Users\Özdal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2173, in getattr raise AttributeError( AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()? I get this error when i do tha

Comment: When you run the code in my answer below, do you still get an `AttributeError`?

Comment: You have asked several questions about python web scraping both today and yesterday. Please accept the answers given to your previous questions if your previous questions were answered accurately and correctly.

Comment: @ShaneBishop Yes, I have and each of them are different problems. I'm trying to learn something and I am new so I think its okay to ask questions.

Comment: And yes i do get AttributeError

Answer (score 1):

Instead of soup.find() use soup.find_all(), that will return a list of those divs, then just take the second.

Comment: File "homework.py", line 32, in <module>
    List1 = Soup1.find_all("div", class_="prp-pages-output").find_all('p')
  File "C:\Users\Özdal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2173, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?


I get this error when i do that

Answer (score 1):

Given the specific URL you provide, the second div can be retrieved like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/May_(M%C3%A1cha)'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')
second_div = soup.find_all(class_='prp-pages-output')[1]
print(second_div)
```

When this code is executed, the output is

```html
<div class="prp-pages-output" lang="en">
<span><span class="pagenum ws-pagenum ws-noexport" data-page-index="10" data-page-name="Page:May (Mácha, 1932).djvu/10" data-page-number="cprght" id="cprght" title="Page:May_(M%C3%A1cha,_1932).djvu/10"><span class="pagenum-inner" id="pageindex_10">​</span></span></span><div class="__dhr" style="visibility:hidden; line-height:0.5em;"> </div>
<div style="display:table; position:relative; margin:0 auto; width:auto;">
<div class="tiInherit" style="text-align:center;">
<div style="line-height:1.4; font-size:92%;">
<p>Privately Printed<br/><span style="letter-spacing: 0.05em;">and Copyrighted</span><br/>November, 1932
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="__dhr" style="visibility:hidden; line-height:0.5em;"> </div> 
</div>
```